# Trim file names to leave only last 5 characters

Tags: bash, terminal

Wondering if you can help. I have thousands of filenames like this:

```
2016-IMG123
IMG124
2018-13727-IMG123
```

I’m trying to create a one liner in terminal to rename all these files in a folder to leave just the last 6 chars.

```
 for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f%?????}"; done
```

This was my starting point but I’ve find using the for loops a little confusing. Most example code talks about removing x number of chars from the front, rather than only leaving 6 chars by removing any additional from the start.

Comment: does removing all the characters up to the last `-` work for your use-case?

Comment: Thank you for the message, unfortunately not, they are a real mess. Only thing I can do I trust that the last 6 chars are correct

Comment: They also don't have any extension, like `.jpg`?

Comment: Yes they have different extensions such as JPG or MOV

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, the idea is the remove a string from the start, which you can do using the variable substitution `${var#string}`. But you want to define what `string` is, and string is everything which remains from `var` after removing the last 5 characters. This is given by `${var%?????}`. So you can use `${var#"${var%?????}"}`. Your code would now read:

```
$ for f in *; do mv -- "$f" "${f#"${f%?????}"}"; done
```

Remark that this method and many others might fail if your initial filename is shorter than 5 characters. You can protect yourself against that with:

```
for f in *; do 
  g="${f#"${f%?????}"}"
  [ "$g" ] &&  mv -- "$f" "$g"
done
```

**Note:** be advised to clearly quote the string `${f%?????}`. This is to avoid unwanted glob-expansions. See the comment of @LeaGris below this question for some details.

Comment: `"${f#"${f%?????}"}"` has the dangerous side-effect of the outer `#` expansion using the inner `%` expansion of `f` as globing pattern grammar. Characters from `f` will be executed as a globing pattern. So if file contains any of `*`, `:`, `[`, `]`, `?` and some more with Bash `extglob` feature, it will lead to highly unexpected results.

Comment: @LéaGris Thanks for the comment. This is why I've place the expansion after the `#` between quotes to disable the globing.

Answer (score 2):

Using standard shell variable expansion to extract basename and pattern:

```bash
# Iterates globing pattern
# ** Always prepend directory name when doing so **
for source in ./*IMG*; do

  # Removes the directory to get only file name
  base_name=${source##*/}

  # Removes everything before the last dash
  destination="${base_name##*-}"

  # Renames without overwriting existing destinations
  mv --no-clobber -- "${source}" "./${destination}"
done
```

If you prefer a one-liner of same:

```bash
for p in ./*IMG*;do b=${p##*/};d="${b##*-}";mv -n -- "$p" "./$d";done
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming no special characters are in the last 6 digits
`for f in *; do mv "$f" "${f:(-6)}"; done`

Answer (score 1):

Because you also need to handle the file extensions, using a bash `regex` is probably the easiest way:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

n=6
regex='^(.*/)?[^/]+([^/]{'$n'}\.[^/.]*|[^/.]{'$n'})$'

for f in ./*.*
do
    [[ $f =~ $regex ]] || continue
    printf '%q %q %q\n' mv "$f" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
done
```

The code will rename the files that have at least 7 characters (excluding the extension). It also handles any path length and files without extension.

---

###### Example

For the following file paths:

```
2016-IMG123.JPEG
./2016-IMG124.MOV
/dir/2018-13727-IMG125.jpg
13727-IMG126
12345.mov
```

You'll get

```bash
mv 2016-IMG123.JPEG IMG123.JPEG
mv ./2016-IMG124.MOV ./IMG124.MOV
mv /dir/2018-13727-IMG125.jpg /dir/IMG125.jpg
mv 13727-IMG126 IMG126
```

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples and attempts, please try following `find` command. I have used `.` for running and picking files from current path here. Simply going through all the files in path and using `bash -c` in it to run `mv` command for renaming files.

```bash
find . -type f -exec bash -c 'mv -n -- "$1" "${1:(-6)}"' bash {} \;
```